# How to get all log files in same date and write to a new log?

Tags: linux, bash, logs

```
TMW_yyyymm=`date +%Y%m --date='tomorrow'`
YDY_yyyymmdd=`date +%Y%m%d --date='yesterday'`
YDY_yyyymm=`date +%Y%m --date='yesterday'`
TODAY=`date +'%Y%m%d'`

SRC_LOG="/home/user/bin/abc.log.${YDY_yyyymmdd}"
HOMEDIR="/home/user/bin"
DEST="/log/user/abc"
```

Above is part of the old script I got from former colleague, and I have to modify it to do the following:

in SRC_LOG, there will be multiple log files having the format abc.log.[yyyymmdd].[0-n]

e.g.

```
 abc.log.20230221.0
 abc.log.20230221.1
 abc.log.20230221.2
```

and so on but I don't know how many log files will be generated on each day.

I want to modify the script to loop through the directory "SRC_LOG" and get all log files from same day, then to combine all log files from that day to a new log file.

The problem is I'm not familiar with bash scripts and don't know how to extract the required files for each day, i.e. how to loop through the suffix .0 .1 .2 ...etc.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

for today:

```
 d=$(date +%Y%m%d)
 find ./dir -name "abc.log.${d}.[0-9]*" -exec cat {} + > "${d}.log'
 #rm ./dir/abc.log.${d}.*
```

Adapt it for other dates

Answer (score 0):

If there are logfiles of **one specific date** in the `$SRC_LOG` directory:

```
printf '%s\n' "$SRC_LOG"/abc.log.* | sort -V | xargs cat > "/path/to/${SRC_LOG##*/}"
```

- `sort -V` makes sure suffix `.0` is sorted before `.10`
- `${SRC_LOG##*/}` strips the directory components from the path as new filename for the combined log

Change the destination directory as needed.

---

If there are logfiles of **various dates** in the `$SRC_LOG` directory:

```
cd "$SRC_LOG"
printf '%s\n' abc.log.* | cut -d. -f-3 | sort -u |
    xargs -I{} sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$1".* | sort -V |
        xargs cat > "/path/to/$1"' sh '{}'
```

Print the filenames of all logfiles, remove the suffix part followed by a unique sort to get all logfile names without suffix.

Then pass the result to `xargs`, start a script for each argument to print the logfile names with suffix, sort the result and `cat` those files into the output file.

---

The safer null-terminated versions for filenames with tabs or newlines using GNU tools would be

```
printf '%s\0' "$SRC_LOG"/*.log.* | sort -zV | xargs -0 cat > "/path/to/${SRC_LOG##*/}"
```

and

```
printf '%s\0' *.log.* | cut -zd. -f-3 | sort -zu |
    xargs -0I{} sh -c 'printf "%s\0" "$1".* | sort -zV |
        xargs -0 cat > "/path/to/$1"' sh '{}'
```